# I can't get the jQuery UI menu widget to accept a selection more than once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am having trouble getting mouse clicks to generate focus events for the jQuery UI 1.9 menu() after it's been selected once.  The first time I click any element in the menu, it calls this select handler:

```
function selcatfunc(event,ui) {
  var td  = event.currentTarget;
  var cid = $(td).attr('data-cid');
  var nam = $(td).find("a").text();
  if (cid) {
    $("#cat-target").text(nam).attr('data-cid', cid);
    $( "#CatMenu" ).hide(); $( "#CatListOverlay" ).hide();
  } else {
    $( "#CatMenuList" ).focus(event, ui);
  }
};
$(function() {
$( "#CatMenuList" ).menu({ select: selcatfunc });
});
```

Each `<li`> in the menu has a data-cid defined so that I know the internal code for the element selected.  The human-readable text is in the :

```
<div id="CatMenu" class="CatList">
<ul id="CatMenuList">
<li data-cid="30.0"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bars, Nightclubs, Sports Bars</a></li>
<li data-cid="200.14"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Used Car</a></li>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

A `<li`> without a data-cid is a category header which expands out into a sub-menu.

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Accessories</b></a>
  <ul>
<li data-cid="10.02"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Men's Accessories</a></li>
<li data-cid="10.04"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Teen Accessories</a></li>
<li data-cid="10.06"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Women's Accessories</a></li>
  </ul></li>
```

Category headers like Accessories aren't meant to be selected, which is why the call to .focus() in the select handler.  cat_target is a  which shows the user what was selected.

The menu works fine the first time I use it.  If I either hide() it or focus() on the sub menu, however, I can't select anything in it again without reloading the dialog.

I ran //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js through the pretty-printer at http://jsbeautifier.org/.  I learned that ALL jQuery mouse events pass to the handler at line 1277 and I added a Firebug logging statement there:

```
  d.handler && (o = d, d = o.handler, f = o.selector), d.guid || (d.guid = p.guid++), i = g.events, i || (g.events = i = {}), h = g.handle, h || (g.handle = h = function (a) {

 console.log("a ", a, " at ", a.type, " h ", h.elem, " args ", arguments);
 return typeof p != "undefined" && (!a || p.event.triggered !== a.type) ? p.event.dispatch.apply(h.elem, arguments)
```

When the menu select succeeds, the console.log statement records a mousedown, a click, a mouseout, and finally object a prints as Object { type= "focus", timeStamp=1351561057050, jQuery182035863344054812873=true, more...}

My select function is called and the text and data-cid are written as expected.  The select function calls hide() on the division which contains the menu.

When I make the menu division reappear using show() and try to select something else, all of the mouse events including click and mouseout occur, but there is no print of a as an object of type "focus."  It appears that hiding the menu broke the mouse click handler so that it no longer generates focus events?

These focus events are how jQuery calls the jQuery UI system; without them, there's no way to get back to the UI.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix the mouse handler?  Or tell me how I've broken the focus mechanism?  Or how I can put it back when I show() the menu?

Comment: hard to filter through all the extra noise in your question. If you need to inspect source of jQuery just remove `min` from the CDN url. Suggest creating a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem